# VirtualBox error Failed to open session of virtual machine macOS (VERR_PDM_TOO_MANY_DEVICES_INSTANCES)

Tags: virtualbox

Too many instances of a device. (VERR_PDM_TOO_MANY_DEVICE_INSTANCES).

Result Code:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: Please provide more contextual info, what were you doing? what have you tried?

Comment: Trying to install MacOS on a virtualbox this is the error  when i start

Comment: cd  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm ""MacOS10"" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbf
VBoxManage setextradata ""MacOS10"" VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion 1.0
VBoxManage setextradata ""MacOS10"" VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct Mac-AA95B1DDAB278895
VBoxManage setextradata ""MacOS10"" VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/1/Config/DeviceKey ourhardworkbythesewordsgaurdedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc
VBoxManage setextradata ""MacOS10"" VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC 1

Comment: Used CMD to install